# Is this topological space metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ carry the product topology $\tau$. Surely, $(X,\tau)$ is compact (Tychonoff).

But is $(X,\tau)$ metrizable and if yes - why?

Is there a metric that generates $\tau$?

Comment: Are you giving $\{0,1,2\}$ the discrete topology? If so, $X$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set. To get an explicit metric, put the discrete metric on $\{0,1,2\}$ and use any of the usual constructions for a metric on the product of countably many metric spaces.

Comment: Ok. Another question. Is $(X,d)$ with $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}2^{-k}\text{ with k maximal so that }x_{[-k,k]}=y_{[-k,k]}, & x\neq y\\0,  & x=y\end{cases}$ a compact metric space?

Comment: What do you mean by $x_{[-k,k]}$?

Comment: I mean the positions from -k to k in the sequence $x\in X$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, it is; it’s a good exercise to prove that this metric does in fact generate the product topology on $X$.

Comment: Do I see it right: If $(X,\tau)$ is a metrizable topological space, then $(X,d)$ is a metric space, where $d$ is any metric that generates the topology $\tau$?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. A metrizable space is one whose topology can be generated by some metric.

Comment: By the way: Does the matrix d I metioned have a special name?

Comment: The metric in your first comment? Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

A countable product of metric spaces is metrizable. In fact, if $d_n$ is a metric on $X_n$, then $$d(x,y) \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}$$ is a metric on $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$$ that generates the product topology.